# Laravel migration errors

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

Created new Laravel 5.2.8 project.

When I want do predefined migration, I get an errors:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1293 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURREN
T_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment pr
imary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `password` varchar(60) not null, `remember_
token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null, `updated_at` timestamp default
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)



[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1293 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURREN
T_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

Migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('name');
   $table->string('email')->unique();
   $table->string('password', 60);
   $table->rememberToken();
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: @Maraboc, thank you! I used MySQL 5.5 version. After update my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Error is exactly telling you what's wrong. See your `CREATE TABLE` statement; you can't have two columns with `timestamp` and default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

SQL:

```
create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment pr
imary key, 
`name` varchar(255) not null, 
`email` varchar(255) not null, 
`password` varchar(60) not null, 
`remember_
token` varchar(100) null, 
`created_at` timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null, <-- here
`updated_at` timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null) <-- here
default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```